# redirect action result in struts2 not working

Tags: java, struts2

```
<action name="doLogin" class="controller.LoginAction">
    <result name="input">login.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">login.jsp</result>
    <result name="success" type="redirectAction">
        <param name="actionName">doStartIndex</param>
    </result>
    <result name="adminpage" type="redirect">adminPage.jsp</result>
</action>

<action name="doStartIndex" class="controller.IndexingAction" method="autoAllocate">
    <result>home.jsp</result>
</action>
```

NOTE:  I'm using struts2.2.1

by using this i'm trying to move from one action to another but I get the following 404:

> localhost:80801/ai/
>   The requested resource (/ai/) is not available.

Comment: Please don't use images for textual information.

Comment: You will need to provide further details; the `"redirectAction"` result type works fine, so something else is wrong. Also, the `"success"` result config can be shortened to `<result name="success" type="redirectAction">doStartIndex</result>`. The `name` attribute can also be removed, but when I do so, I put it at the top of the results so it stands out more as being the default result.

Comment: please make struts.devMode = true and rerun your code, you can then place the stacktrace here

Comment: @Dave Newton you are correct and I got this problem fixed by removing constructor in my action class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one of my scenario I was in need of creation a bean class but since the action class has the same bean elements that which I want to create in my new bean class except the parameterized constructor.

So I was testing to use the action class inserted to creating a new bean class. First I was wrong that an action class can also have parameterized constructor and while I tried to work with that my action, it fails to work and returns to the same page where I initiated that action and even I did not get any stack trace too.

So People keep remember that we should not try to create  parameterized constructor for an action class with out creating a default constructor. I hope about this last line I'm correct if I need any correction please correct me.